# Detect markup symbols inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea on the page. And decide validate this element. I insert simple text and in js I check the length this element. But when I delete all text I can save without any problem. I see in firebug and in textarea I find

```
<ul></ul><br/>
```

}

// js

```
 for(var i=0; length > i; i++){
        value = textElements[i].value;
        if(value == "" ||(value == "<br/>" && element.tagName == "TEXTAREA")){
            full = false;
            emptyElements.push(elements[i]);
        } else {
            empty = false;
            elements[i].style.borderColor = "";
            elements[i].style.border = "";
        }
    }
```

Ad HTML

```
 <br /><div id="edit-contentFrame-form:editor" style="visibility:hidden"><textarea id="edit-contentFrame-form:editor_input" name="edit-contentFrame-form:editor_input"><h3></h3><h3></h3><h3><br/></h3><ul>
</ul></textarea></div>
```

I try to find existing way to resolve this problem. But nothing to find.

```
///EDITED

function isEmptyTextArea(){
                var str = document.getElementById('edit-contentFrame-form:editor_input').value;
                var regexp = new RegExp("(&lt;+[\w]+&gt;+)*", "g");
                var matches_array_tags = str.replace(regexp, '');

                if(matches_array_tags.length == 0){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem with next js function

```
function isCompleteTagContent(str){
    var re= /<\S[^><]*>/g;
    var matches_array_tags = str.replace(re, "");

    if(matches_array_tags.trim().length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace and strip all the "markup symbols" tags from the textarea if you don't want people to be able to input html.

Comment: I dont want replace or strip symbols for user. I just want to find the way to check textarea when it consists from only marup symbols

Comment: If I make a copy textarea content. How I can replace all "markup symbols" with regexp?

Comment: Regex can do that too, there is a .test() method "that tests for a match in a string. It returns true or false." you can use with it (see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Working_with_Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @sweeramylase For that I shold create array with all mark-up symbols or search smth like `\<{1}{w+}\>{1}`

Comment: You want to be something like: \(<+[\w/]+>+)*\
The <+ matches >1 opening bracket.
The [\w/]+ matches any letter and / symbol.
The >+ matches >1 closing bracket.
The (   )* around the whole thing matches any 0 or more of that "tag" pattern

Comment: I add my js funtion above. Please, check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var txtarea = document.getElementById('txtarea');
if(escape(txtarea.value) === '')
     // textarea is empty
```

Not including whitespaces:

```
if(escape(txtarea.value.trim()) === '')
     // textarea is empty (not including whitespaces)
```

Comment: `value = escape(textElements[i]).value;` Intellige IDEA give a hiny that escape is deprecated function

Comment: No, it doesn't help encodeUri just replace symbols on UTF-escape-sequence. Textarea value which contains markup symbols will not empty